# Why doesn't this assembly code delete the file with ".lnk" extension?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, file-management, emu8086

I am trying to delete a file that has ".lnk" extension using assembly 8086 architecture. When I write "jmp DELETE" after "mov si, dx" and skip the inner, back1, back2, back3 part, my code deletes all the file, but when it checks if it has .lnk extension character by character, it doesn't delete any of them, not even the file with .lnk extension . Why is it happening?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
FILE DB "*", 0
DTA DB 128H DUP(?)   
FILENAME DB 50 DUP(?)
.CODE

MAIN PROC  

    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX

    ;SET DTA
    MOV DX,OFFSET DTA
    MOV AH,1AH
    INT 21H

    ;FIRST SEARCH
    MOV DX,OFFSET FILE 
    MOV CX,0
    MOV AH,4EH
    INT 21H
    JC QUIT

OUTER_LOOP:


    ;DELETE
    LEA DX,DTA+30 
    mov si, dx 

    inner:
    cmp [si], 0
    je back1
    inc si
    jmp inner

    back1:
    dec si
    cmp [si],'K'
    je back2
    jmp NEXT

    back2:
    dec si
    cmp [si],'N'
    je back3
    jmp NEXT

    back3:

    dec si
    cmp [si], 'L'


    delete:
    LEA DX,DTA+30 
    MOV AH,41H
    INT 21H


    ;INITIATE NEXT SEARCH
    NEXT:
    MOV DX,OFFSET FILE 
    MOV CX,0
    MOV AH,4FH
    INT 21H
    JC QUIT

    JMP OUTER_LOOP



QUIT:
    MOV AX,4C00H
    INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
    END MAIN
```

Comment: What assembler are you using, and out of curiosity did it happen to throw any warnings (masm or tasm?)? I would expect most assemblers to complain about all the lines that look similar to this `cmp [si], 'L'` . Some assemblers will treat that as comparing the 16-bit _WORD_ at [si], not the byte.

Comment: All the lines _like_ `cmp [si], 'L'` (4 of them) should be something like `cmp byte ptr  [si], 'L'`

Comment: I am using tasm assembler.

Comment: and right now I am just running my code in an emulator named "emu8086".

Comment: Ah, EMU8086 that's a different beast. I'm not even sure how deleting a file or how the emulated OS even works on that. So you are saying you can't delete files while running under EMU8086? I'm asking so that I can retag your question if necessary.

Comment: yes, this code works on the "MyBuild" directory in EMU8086. But nothing gets deleted.

Comment: Why not step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: I did. And the it works there. I meant all the registers and variables hold the value it should be holding, but nothing happens in the directory.

Comment: In DOS type file wildcards, `*` only matches files that have no extension. To match all files, you need `*.*`, or to match `.lnk` files use `*.lnk`.

Answer (score 2):

These points might interest you:

- Change your filemask to

  ```
  *.*
  ```
- Why do you set up such a large DTA?.

  ```
  DTA 44 dup(?)
  ```
- Always write `cmp byte ptr [si], ...`
- Don't stop comparing after the 3 characters. Add a fourth compare to see if the point is present. Then you'll know that *LNK* is indeed a file extension.
- Your 4Fh DOS call doesn't need the CX and DX parameters.
- You don't interpret the result from

  ```
  cmp [si], 'L'
  ```

Comment: I did everything you said. But still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Try to delete another type of file (*.MY) with your program. Maybe files with the .LNK extension are **in use** by emu8086 and therefore _protected_.

Comment: @user3144770 : Have you considered that the file names could be upper and lower case in EMU8086? Is it possible the files you are looking for are `lnk` and not `LNK`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch DOS always capitalizes its filenames. So emu8086 should not treat this any different.

Comment: @user3144770 if that was the case then when I skipped all the checking part and did a jump after "mov si, dx" why all the files including the file with ".LNK" extension got deleted?

Comment: Then you effectively asked to clear out the whole directory because of the __*__ wildcard symbol that represents **every** file.

Comment: EMU8086 has a lot of different quirks based on the underlying file system, and although real DOS may return them in all uppercase, EMU8086 may not (unless the underlying file system was also also returned them in all upper case). Most modern windows file systems will write file names case sensitive but compare case insensitive. I'd bet anything that if you have a file in `c:\emu8086\mybuild\test.lnk` that it would appear as `test.lnk` in EMU8086, not `TEST.LNK`

Comment: @MichaelPetch and user harmione To address the case issue and to simplify your program, why don't you use a filemask of __*.lnk__ ? Every file found, if any, will fulfill the requirements.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. In fact `"*.lnk"` as the search pattern on EMU8086 should return back all files with `.LNK` regardless of case. So `"*.lnk"` would return back all file with extension `lnk`, `LNK`, `LnK`, etc. You avoid having to compare file extensions at all.

Comment: @harmione finally decided to drag out EMU8086. It is in fact case sensitive when returning file names, and the file search is not case sensitive. I used a search pattern of `"*.lnk"` instead of `"*"`, removed the extension checking code and simply went to deleting the file as they were found. The files disappeared here.